# javascript resolveLocalFileSystemURL triggering both success and fail callbacks

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback, file-exists, cordova-plugin-file

I am doing a simple file check in my cordova app using the following back to back commands:

```
function initWhipData(dir) {
   console.log("DIR = " +dir) ;
}

//Test:
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fPath + "whipdata.json",
   function() { console.log("TEST File Exists")},
   function() { console.log("TEST File doesnt exist") }
) ;

//Actual:
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fPath + "whipdata.json",
   initWhipData(10),
   initWhipData(20)
) ;
```

In console.  I get the following and can't understand why:

```
TEST File Exists  // expected
Dir = 10  // expected
Dir = 20  // not expected
```

In the second file check, both success and fail are being called.  What am I doing wrong...and not understanding?

I then tried the following and got my expected results:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fPath + "whipdata.json",
   function() {initWhipData(10)},
   function() { initWhipData(20)} 
) ;
```

It prints out "Dir = 10".  Obviously I am not understanding something that I thought I understood.  Why does wrapping my functions in a function work while just directly referencing the function as success/fail callbacks does not work?

Answer (score 2):

This is how we **call a function** and get the result `var a = initWhipData(10);`
And this is how we **get the reference** of a function `var a = initWhipData;`

I mean, you're trying to call initWhipData function then pass the result of it as a parameter instead of passing it's reference.
That's why initWhipData(10) and initWhipData(20) will be called first then the returned value will being passed as a parameter.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fPath + "whipdata.json",
   initWhipData(10),
   initWhipData(20)
);
```

Below are the example on how to pass a callback function..

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fPath + "whipdata.json",
   successCallback, //If success then call this function
   errorCallback //If error happen then call this function
);

function successCallback(){
    initWhipData(10)
}
function errorCallback(){
    initWhipData(20)
}
```

Comment: This was the part I needed to understand and/or was missing:  `you're trying to call initWhipData function then pass the result of it as a parameter instead of passing it's reference`  - thanks!!